# A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, java-8, gradle-task

[image: I got this error today, yesterday the build was working perfectly i dont know what happened today, please help me, also flutter doctor is showing no issues]

A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> File 'C:\Users\Anoushk\AndroidStudioProjects\crud_app\build\app\intermediates\annotation_processor_list\debug\annotationProcessors.json' specified for property 'processorListFile' does not exist.

Comment: flutter doctor shows no issues also this was working yesterday on opening studio today and running project i got this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issues by deleteing the .gradle file in the android folder in the project file

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the .GRADLE file in the ANDROIDPROJECTFILE - - locate the project folder and delete the .gradle file and rebuild